# Amazon S3 - Create directory structure programmatically

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am developing a node.js application. I am using an AWS EC2 instance with MySQL. I am using Amazon S3 for my storage. In my application, each user has a repository. Each repository has multiple folders and each folder has multiple files.

Is it a good idea to programmatically create an S3 folder for each user to achieve a directory structure?

Comment: sure why not sounds good. part of user creation provisioning.

Comment: No need to make a folder before uploading the files - S3 doesn't actually have them - they are basically just key prefixes. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html If you create a key `what/ever/something.jpg` the console acts as if the `what` and `ever` folders exist, but no actual objects for them need to be created.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon offloads the pain to create the parent and nested sub folders when you have to put the keys inside multiple sub folders.

You can certainly consider using folders programmatically.

**For instance**

If you want to create a file under subdolder, then under a subsubfolder- you can simply put key as `subfolder/subsubfolder/file.txt`

The operation would be performing like - 
`create if not exists`